# Code to fetch datas from web servers using Odata via json in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, odata

I am new to iPhone.i am doing a application using WCF Dataservices and odata via json.does any one can help me in fetching datas using Odata via json in xcode by giving some example codes..

Thanks in advance,
Sarath

Comment: i dont hav an exact code. i am trying to get a functional code for fetching data from web service using Odata via json..

Comment: what ar all the frameworks i should use to run this?

Comment: Not an Xcode question; retagged.

Answer (score 0):

OData4ObjC is an open source OData client for Objective C and contains a number of samples. I'd recommend starting there: https://github.com/OData/OData4ObjC.